# What type of capacitor do I need to stabilize USB voltage?

Tags: mosfet, usb, fet

I am trying to use a "FET" (https://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Interface_Circuits#Using_a_FET) to switch the power supply to a USB speaker from my Raspberry Pi.

It's working well, however when I turn the volume to greater than 60%, the speaker plays a sound but then dies and disconnects, only to reconnect via USB 2 seconds later.

I'm thinking that the voltage is probably dropping too much, but I'm not sure.

I'm using the NTE2987 Logic Level MOSFET N−Channel and a 100k resistor to switch the USB ground, just as described in the above link.
I've tried to use multiple 100uf capacitors to "smoothen" the voltage, with no effect.

Appreciate advise on how I can make this work!

Comment: Please draw a schematic and tell what model speaker it is. At least tell how much it draws current and how much the Pi can supply. But based on what you describe, switching USB ground to a device sounds like a bad idea in many ways. Also putting multiple 100uF capacitors to USB power pins sounds like a bad idea too. It will  Be careful not to fry your devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s very likely your speaker is drawing more current from the USB port than the R-pi can deliver. The port current limiter is kicking in, momentarily powering down the port. You will not be able to fix that by adding caps.

Instead, you can increase this USB power limit in software, by changing /boot/config.txt. More here: https://hackaday.com/2015/04/06/more-power-for-raspberry-pi-usb-ports/

Comment: Thats a good point. I'm currently powering the circuit & speaker via the +5v/ground gpio pins of the pi. Since I want to control the gate of the Mosfet from one of the gpio's.
Before cutting the USB cable, the speaker was working fine at 100% volume, through usb power.
But your comment might still be valid, since the gpio power pin might not yield enough power...

Comment: The usb speaker shortly playing and then turning off, actually arises when I drive the Gate of the Mosfet via the GPIO pin (tried pin 36 & 40) (it works when directly connecting it to the 5v gpio pin (pin 2))... any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the FET on the high side or the low side? In any event, you should be using a P channel FET.

Comment: Using it on the low side. Let me try a p channel fet

Comment: The p channel should be on the high side by the way.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'm using the p channel mosfet on the high side now and it works!
I'm setting the GPIO of the pi to "input" to turn usb off and to "output drive low" to turn it on... it works, but i'm not sure if thats the rigth way to do it ;)

Comment: 'input' is probably using the pull-up inside the device, which is kinda ok, but it'd be better if you set it to 'output drive high' to improve noise immunity.